# Jenkins Git Parameter Plugin - useRepository not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using this plugin to list branches. However the Jenkins job in question builds multiple repos, and the SCM is configured for the initial repo. Therefore, if I leave the useRepository empty it correctly lists the branches in that repo. However if I specific a different repo it always fails to populate the list. I have tried so many ways of defining the repo url (myRepo, myRepo.git, https://[fullPath]/myRepo.git etc). Is anyone else having these issues or know how to solve it?

I am currently using the Jenkins Job Configuration UI, not the pipeline script to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the issue was that I need to specify all the repos used in the job in the pipeline section. I assume this is for the credential information.

[image]